# Applying a function to dataframe column containing datetimes

Tags: python, pandas, time, apply

Here is a piece of code i tried. Am trying to round off the times to nearest hour by applying the roundtime() function to each entry in 'Booking Time' column of my dataframe. However, the rounding does not apply to the column and the entries are as it is.

```
import datetime as dt
def roundtime(t):
    if t.minute >= 30:
        return t.replace(second=0, minute=0, hour=(t.hour+1)%24)
    else:
        return t.replace(second=0, minute=0)
df2= df.copy()
df2['Booking Time']= pd.to_datetime(df2['booking_created']).dt.time
df2['Booking Time'].apply(roundtime)
df2.head()
```

Can someone point out the fault?

Comment: Can you add some sample data 2-3 datetimes with expected output, [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need apply function to datetimes:

```
df2['Booking Time']= pd.to_datetime(df2['booking_created']).apply(roundtime)
```

Or if need apply to times:

```
df2['Booking Time']= pd.to_datetime(df2['booking_created']).dt.time.apply(roundtime)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. I wasn't using it inplace maybe.

Comment: FYI `apply` doesn't do inplace. It will return the applied Series or Dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without a separate function

```
import numpy as np
df['Booking Time'] = (np.where(pd.to_datetime(df['booking_created'],format='%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S').dt.minute > 30 
                , pd.to_datetime(df['booking_created'],format='%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S').dt.ceil('30min')
                , pd.to_datetime(df['booking_created'],format='%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S')))
```